# Is there a reason why some ac/dc adapters don't have a grounding pin?

Tags: grounding, adapter, ac-dc

I'm searching for an AC/DC adapter of 6v 300mA, but I can't find one with a grounding pin (E-type). Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: None of the reasons to have grounding apply to it.

Comment: Grounding is typically required if the adapter enclosure is conductive.  Since most enclosures are plastic nowadays, there is no danger of electrocution even during/after internal circuitry catastrophic failure.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY: well, it depends what's connected to the DC output. If it can generate high voltages (old laptops that had CCFL inverter are a good example) you'll find that they had grounded AC/DC adapters.

Comment: @Simon Ravelingien: why do you think you need one [with grounding]? What do you want to power with it?

Comment: Why do high voltage outputs need a grounding pin?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff because I have an 8 year old dj mixing panel, that produces a lot of noise when I connect it to my speakers. So I was wondering if I could solve this by connecting my panel with a grounded adapter

Comment: No, that won't solve your noise problem.

Comment: DJ equipment is notorious for [pin 1 problems](http://www.rane.com/note165.html).

Comment: @Simon Ravelingien: By the way, since your problem is about professional sound equipment, you should ask your real, (i.e. noise) problem at http://sound.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types of power supplies are always *isolated*.  That means there is no direct connection between the inputs and the outputs.  You should be able to connect a ohmmeter between any input lead and any output lead and read infinite (or very high) resistance.

Given that there is no electrocution path between input and output, and all the dangerous stuff is encased in insulating material, there is nothing to be gained by adding a ground connection.  The device is designed for the output to "float" relative to the input.  Forcing some part of the input circuitry to ground doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Care to clarify "These types"? Because [this one](http://superuser.com/a/977605/345617) is not of "these types" . In fact I dare say most HP laptops of that era had grounded adapters like that one.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Probably safe to say that at 6 V and 300 mA, we're talking about the detestable wallwarts, a la http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/WSU060-1250/237-1421-ND/3094947.

Comment: Well, in that case I agree. I have not seen a grounded/earthed wall wart. I have a UK-plug one that has a fake grounding pin: even though it's metal, internally it's not connected to anything; numerous more have the same pin of plastic; it's needed for the UK sockets to work. It would be more interesting to know why wall warts are never grounded/earthed. I'm not sure if it's regulatory or just so the market evolved.

Comment: @OlinLathrop What do you mean with floating?

Comment: @Simon: Floating is same as isolated in this context.

Answer (score 1):

if the adapter has no ground because it doesnt have to like Olin stated ,then clearly it would be cheaper to manufacture which is very important in the cost sensitive market.Having no ground also reduces the costs of approvals because it for example makes HV clearances easier to meet .The earth leakage current flows through the output instead of the ground which means there is no earth leakage current into a floating load ,but HF components of this current can muck up sensitive electronics.If the adapter is tested for common mode conducted EMC when running into a floating load it will appear to perform very well!The point is that product approvals make up a large part of the design cost on anything to do with mains that uses relatively orthodox circuitry.